# Holomorphic series of functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let
$f_n : G \rightarrow D = { z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 }$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions. Reason whether the following are correct and if not give a counterexample.

1. if $f_n$, n=1,2,… injective, then the following $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n $ exists and is also injective.
2. if $f_n$, n=1,2,… injective, then there is a convergent subsequence, whose limiting function is also injective.
3. if $f_n$ has at most 4 zeros, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$, then $f$ also has either at most 4 zeros, or is zero itself.

So I am not 100% sure but think (3) is correct because of Hurwitz? But I have no idea for the other two, as injective sequences are not covered in my book.

Comment: Could you say who is $G$? Any open set in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @GiulioR: yes, exactly, it is not further specified

Comment: $G=\mathbb D$ and $f_n=z/n, n \ge 1$ odd and $f_n=z/n+1/2, n \ge 2$ even (so $|f_n(z)| <1, |z|<1$ while clearly $f_n$ injective) then $f_n \to 0, n$ odd and $f_n \to 1/2, n$ even so neither 1,2 are true; if you change 2 to convergent whose limiting function is constant or convergent the result is true from Montel and Hurwitz

Comment: @Conrad: thank you! And is three correct because of Hurwitz?

Comment: yes of course since if $f$ is non zero and has $5$ or more zeroes then also $f_n$ have eventually 5 zeroes or more

Comment: @Conrad: thank you very much